# pass table name as parameter to cursor in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

While implementing cursor I am unable to pass the table name as parameter to the select query declared in the cursor. How could I pass the table name as parameter to taht query ?

```
DELIMITER //

Drop PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetRecord;
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRecord(IN hr int,IN TableName varchar(50))
BEGIN
declare done int DEFAULT 0;
declare ID int DEFAULT 0;
declare name varchar(25);

declare cur1 cursor for SELECT id ,name FROM TableName;
declare continue handler for not found set done=1;
SET @query = concat('update Student set no=no+? where id=?');   
PREPARE stmt from @query;
    open cur1;  
    igmLoop: loop
         fetch cur1 into ID,name;
        SELECT ID;
         IF done = 1 THEN 
         LEAVE igmLoop;
         END IF;
        SET @id = ID;
        SET @HR =hr;
        EXECUTE stmt USING @HR,@id; 

    end loop igmLoop;
    close cur1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: MYSQL cannot Compile and Optimize and save an execution Plan of an SP if it does know the Table Name. So you cannot do this as a Stored Proceedure

Comment: So, is there any other way to implement this logic? can i store multiple records in a single variable and use them one by one ? is there any way other than cursor to implement this..?

Comment: Maybe with a stored function? Execution plans aren't pregenerated for functions